# How do I get the values of checkboxes when using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

Code in file *view.html*:

```
<label ng-repeat = "agents in acesslevel |filter:{acesslevel: 'Agent'}">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type= "checkbox"
               ng-model="agentsSelected"
               checklist-value="agents.name"
               ng-true-value=agents ng-false-value="'NO'">
        {{agents.name}}
    </div>
</label>
```

Where acesslevel is JSON format data I'm getting from my database.

For example,

```
{
  "acesslevel": "Quality",
  "dob": "1995-02-03",
  "name": "anjali",
  "password": "tanya",
  "username": "anju",
  "createdAt": "2014-07-02T16:26:26.816Z",
  "updatedAt": "2014-07-02T16:26:26.816Z",
  "id": "53b432b230aaa394278522ca"
},

{
  "acesslevel": "Agent",
  "dob": "1995-02-03",
  "name": "christopher",
  "password": "tanya",
  "username": "anju",
  "createdAt": "2014-07-02T16:26:48.170Z",
  "updatedAt": "2014-07-02T16:26:48.170Z",
  "id": "53b432c830aaa394278522cb"
}
```

This particular code in HTML is displaying the names of agents in acesslevel (in above case it would display christopher)

How would I get the value of the selected checkbox in the controller?

I want to insert this selected agent's data in a new table in my database server.

Comment: What do you want the checkbox to affect? ng-model is what the checkbox binds to, but you bind it to the same thing for all agents? If you use `ng-model="agents.isChecked"` you can get the value of isChecked for each accesslevel in your controller.

Comment: @Patrick i want all the agents who are clicked in my controller so that from there i can sen it on my mongodb server.

Comment: And why do you bind the checkbox to agentsSelected instead of a property on the agents instance? Does that not solve your problem?

Comment: Nope agentsSelected is giving me undefined in my controller.

Comment: What? I'm telling you to use a property of the agents instance, not the agentsSelected (which is bound to your specific $scope). Can you not use `ng-model="agents.isChecked` and read that property in your controller? You haven't specified what boolean value you are trying to affect.

Comment: *"[accesslevel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/access#Noun)"* is misspelt as *"acesslevel"*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using ng-model which binds to (what I suppose is) an array, but Angular expects a Boolean value (true or false).

If you instead bind to a property of the instances of your filtered accesslevel array you can extract that data later in your controller

```
<label ng-repeat = "agents in acesslevel |filter:{acesslevel: 'Agent'}">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type= "checkbox"
               ng-model="agents.isSelected" <!-- bind to another value -->
               checklist-value="agents.name"
               ng-true-value="agents"
               ng-false-value="'NO'">
        {{agents.name}}
    </div>
</label>
```

Your controller can access this property later if you for instance have a method to submit values to your backend.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var selectedAgents = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.acesslevel, function (agent) {
        if (agent.acesslevel == 'Agent' && agent.isSelected) {
            selectedAgents.push(agent);
        }
    });
    // Here you can make calls to your backend with the selectedAgents variable.

};
```

Comment: Works, Thank you very much.Was irritated because of that
Very new to angular-js, just started a week ago, so dunno a lot.
Btw any book or article recommeded for angular? And any idea on using select2 in angular via ng-repeat?